# Calculating Degrees Minutes Seconds (DMS) to nearest tenth of second in ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, coordinates, degrees-minutes-seconds

Is there a simple way to calculate coordinates in DMS to the nearest tenth second?  I need DD MM **SS.s** (not DD MM **SS.sss**).  By default, ArcMap calculates out to 3 decimal places.  I just need it rounded to the 1st decimal place.

I have ArcMap 10.2 and XTools Pro.

Comment: Besides just formatting the string yourself? In which language/context do you need this implemented? Please update the question.

Comment: I need to be able to show the coordinates in the attribute table in DMS format, rounded to 1 decimal point (ex. 12 34 56.7).  I could just Add Field and round it myself, but I have close to 100 points.  It seems like the functionality should exist since it already takes it out to 3 decimal places.  Does this help?

Comment: Would you be able to edit your question to revise it with the above details, and also to specify precisely where you are viewing these DMS values, please?

Comment: Um, what is the problem with Add Field and using Field Calculator?

Answer (score 1):

Your coordinates are stored in decimal degrees, DMS is just one display method. You could modify the display using the field properties. Even if you force the precision of your field, but this will round to number stored in decimal degrees which will then be converted in DMS.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  However, when I change the number format like you suggested, the longitude goes from -81..... to 38 degrees.  The latitude also does not convert correctly.  Any ideas?